# Final answer of integral with new 'substituted' limits is different than original limits

Tags: integration

Basically, I had to integrate

$$ \int_{-0.5}^0 \frac{x}{(3-4x-4x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}.$$

I completed the square and used the trig substitution $2x+1 = 2 \sin(Q)$.

At the end after integration, I was left with $\frac{-\cos(Q)}{2} - \frac{(Q)}{4}$.

Now I dont particularly like changing everything back in $x$ just to evaluate the integral so I changed the limits to suit my substitution.

Basically when

$$x = -0.5 \hspace{1.5cm}  Q = 0$$
$$x = 0   \hspace{1.5cm}       Q = \frac{\pi}{6}$$

However my final answer is not right according to the book. It is right however if I substitute all the way back and use the original $x$ values. So my question is, what is wrong with my new limits of integration?

EDIT: The answer I'm getting is roughly $0.032$ when the actual answer is $0.06$. I checked the integral on Wolfram and noticed the same thing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your limits.

$$-\frac{\cos(\pi/6)}{2}-\frac{\pi/6}{4}+\frac{\cos(0)}{2}+\frac{0}{4}=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}-\frac{\pi}{24}+\frac{1}{2}\approx-0.06$$